# Windows MSA accounts: can I perform WMI / WinRM commands between two different servers with MSA accounts?

Tags: windows, wmi, winrm, spn

Microsoft allows remote connections to be setup between two Windows servers with MSA (Managed Service Accounts), but seemingly only for a limited range of applications (SQL, IIS, Exchange):

- [Managed Service Accounts (MSA) and SQL 2012: Practical Tips](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2014/02/03/managed-service-accounts-msa-and-sql-2012-practical-tips.aspx)
- [Register a Service Principal Name for Kerberos Connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms191153.aspx)

As I understand it, if an MSA account can register an SPN (Service Principle Name) for the service it needs, it can perform inter-system communication with another server.

Here's what I would like to do: I would like to be able to use (Windows Remote monitoring services) WinRM / WMI to run the following monitoring command:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem
```

But I don't want to use a general AD account, because there is a 30 day credential expiry that I don't want to have to keep dealing with.